# XmlSerializer writing data containing characters which must be escaped

Tags: c#, regex, xml, xml-serialization

is there an way to serialize a xml with text delimiters?
I've a xml document with some regex string, but if I execute my
application I got a parsing error. I'm sure the reason for this is the
unescaped regex in the xml document. Is there a way to use something like 
text delimiters? If not, how can I escape the following regex: `"<a href="(?<link>.+?)" rel="bookmark">.+?</a>"?`

Comment: These are not "text delimiters". They are characters which are invalid in XML unless they are escaped, or written in a CDATA section.

Comment: Actually, I'm surprised that the XML Serializer doesn't escape those characters for you. Can you please show a small code example which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap it like this:

```
<![CDATA[".+?)" rel="bookmark">.+?"?]]>
```

Otherwise you have to escape each special character.

More informations:

[CDATA Sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256076%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[List of XML and HTML character entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)